# Scientific Notation in SIunitx

Tags: siunitx

I want to write something like (3.45E-10 \pm 6E-12) inside a table and I want the numbers to appear in scientific notation. I am getting and error and this only happens when I use scientific notation, not with normal numbers like (4.3 \pm 1.2). Can someone please help?

Comment: Would `\num[{scientific-notation = true, separate-uncertainty = true}]{3.45(6)e-10}` work in your table? Not tested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing `(3.45E-10 \pm 6E-12)`, I would recommend using `(3.45 \pm 6)E-10`. It's neater that way, especially so since you are typesetting this in a table.

Onto the code itself: I'm not doing it in a table because it's too troublesome xD Anyhow, this should have the same effect in a table:

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \num[{scientific-notation = true, separate-uncertainty = true}]{3.45(6)e-10}
\end{document}
```

The option `scientific-notation` ensures the number that you pass in the argument is in scientific notation, while `separate-uncertainty` ensures the number appears as a `\pm` like you wanted.

### Output

[image: uncertain about the second dp]

Comment: Why does `\SI{4.22(4.04)e-6}{mol\per\meter\squared}` result in an error, while `\SI{4.22(6)e-6}{mol\per\meter\squared}` doesn't?